# Query with in an Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Generate a list of pilots that have the highest number of flight hours for each model of plane. Include columns for the pid, the model, and the hourslogged.

This is what I have tried - I am very new to SQL:

```
select
    pid, hourslogged 
from 
    flightskills f
join    
   (select 
        model, max(hourslogged) as Hourslogged 
    from 
        flightskills
    group by 
        model) h on f.model = h.model
```

this output is wrong

```
PID MODEL   HOURSLOGGED
1   A-10        387
4   A-10        387
6   A-10        387
7   A-10        387
3   F-117A  254
4   F-117A  254
5   F-117A  254
6   F-117A  254
1   F-15E   450
2   F-15E   450
3   F-15E   450
4   F-15E   450
6   F-15E   450
1   F-16    827
6   F-16        827
1   F-22        900
3   F-22        900
4   F-22        900
5   F-22        900
6   F-22        900
6   X-100   100
```

Want something like this

```
PID MODEL   HOURSLOGGED
1   A-10        387
3   F-117A  254
4   F-15E   450
1   F-16    827
3   F-22        900
6   X-100   100
```

Comment: prefix your columns `pid` and `hourslogged` with table and subquery aliases (`f.` or `h.`), since db cannot decide from which dataset should select ...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: And when you add aliases you still don't get the right answer, you must also add another JOIN-condition: `on f.model = h.model
       and f.Hourslogged = h.Hourslogged` to get the row with the high value. Later you will learn how to use *Windowed Aggregates* to get the same result in a simpler way, i.e. `row_number` or `max over`

Comment: Ok thank you I understand now.  Had to join on both model and hours.

Comment: Joining on hourslogged would be a risky approach. What if two pilots logged the same amount of hours?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select f.*
from flightskills f
where f.hourslogged = (select max(f2.hourslogged) 
                       from flightskills f2
                       where f2.model = f.model
                      );
```

Comment: @MrBlack . . . That is not a helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your query

```
select pid, hourslogged 
  from flightskills f
  join    
     (select model, max( hourslogged) as Hourslogged 
        from flightskills
       group by model) h    
    on f.model = h.model
```

there are two `PID` columns and two `HOURSLOGGED` columns available when the query is being compiled, `f.PID` and `h.PID`, and `f.HOURSLOGGED` and `h.HOURSLOGGED`. In the SELECT list you need to tell the database which of the columns you want to use. To fix the problem you might change your query to

```
select f.pid, h.hourslogged 
  from flightskills f
  join    
     (select model, max( hourslogged) as Hourslogged 
        from flightskills
       group by model) h    
    on f.model = h.model
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83036b1f2183c7940c5835f6488374cd)

Best of luck with the rest of your assignment.

Comment: This is close but here is  its totaling all the hours for the pilots
PID MODEL HOURSLOGGED
1 A-10         387
4 A-10         387
6 A-10         387
7 A-10         387
3 F-117A 254

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need to go for a nested query. As you are using Oracle, you can leverage [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). Well a little bit of a subquery is still needed, as an analtyic function does not go in a WHERE condition directly (it runs *after* the where condition is evaluated).

```
SELECT
  pid, 
  model, 
  hourslogged, 
FROM (
SELECT
  pid, 
  model, 
  hourslogged, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY model ORDER BY hourslogged DESC) AS rn
FROM flightskills
) WHERE rn = 1
```

You can use different ranking methodologies instead of the simple [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#i86310). [`DENSE_RANK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions052.htm#SQLRF00633) for example will treat the situation with two pilots logging the same amount of hours differenly (they will show both up instead of randomly one of two).

Above approach goes directly after the top record by `hourslogged` for each model. You do this in two steps 1./ Rank 2./ Select top rank (`rn = 1`).